# Sticky Menu, at a certain height

Tags: html, css, menu, sticky

I am trying to replicate this sticky meny effect: http://tbwachiatdayla.com/
I want the menu to become sticky at a certain height. How can I do that? Position: fixed; at a a top: 100px height let's say

Comment: I found this. Might be helpful. http://ruturaj.net/automatic-header-stick-to-scroll-with-jquery/

Comment: that is prolly jquery, you cant do that on pure css, just fixed position.

Comment: This might help http://addyosmani.com/blog/rocketbar/

Answer (score 1):

I was browsing sticky menus and came across this:http://jsfiddle.net/vyHQC/

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(document).scrollTop(), //get page y value 
        header = $("#block-menu");
    if(y >= 300)  {
        header.css({position: "fixed", "top" : "0", "left" : "0"});
    } else {
        header.css("position", "relative");
    }
});
```

Someone else wrote the code, so I won't take credit, but I will post the answer.
[Position fixed on a certain point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922045/position-fixed-on-a-certain-point)