# Position fixed on a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, fixed

i'm having trouble with the position of a div.
I'd like this div to be position relative until the page has been scrolled for a certain amount of pixels.
In details I have a div(#block-menu) that is almost 300px down the page, I want it to become fixed when it hits the top.
I've tried using this code, but doesn't seem to work properly...

```
var header = $("#block-menu");
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300  {
        header.css({position: "fixed", "top" : "0"});
    } else {
        header.css("position", "relative");
    }
});
</script>`
```

the CSS:

```
#block-menu {
    background: rgb(27, 85, 131);
    position: relative;
}
```

the HTML:

```
<div id="#first-block" height="100px"></div>
<div id="second-block" height="200px"></div>
<div id="block-menu"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: "but doesn't seem to work properly..."   Which means???

Comment: I don't know, something like it looks like doesn't work as it should, I think..I'm trying to be understood as I can ;) thanks as well

Answer (score 6):

Is this what your trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/vyHQC/

JS

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(document).scrollTop(),
        header = $("#block-menu");
    if(y >= 300)  {
        header.css({position: "fixed", "top" : "0", "left" : "0"});
    } else {
        header.css("position", "relative");
    }
});
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#block-menu {
    background: rgb(27, 85, 131);
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

#first-block {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}

#second-block {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 100%;
    background: purple;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="first-block"></div>
<div id="block-menu"></div>
<div id="second-block"></div>
```

Comment: yes your exemple is perfect, I've tried to copy and past the code but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: I've just copied and past the code in my head between the script tags <script type="text/javascript">$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(document).scrollTop(),
        header = $("#block-menu");
    if(y >= 300)  {
        header.css({position: "fixed", "top" : "0", "left" : "0"});
    } else {
        header.css("position", "relative");
    }
});</script>

Comment: Great answer, super efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a plugin that already work and is already tested in all browsers, to do that?

http://stickyjs.com/

Comment: how do I use this plug in? it would be perfect, I didn't know about it.. thanks :)

Comment: I'm trying with the plugin, but nothing, I've added this two lines of code in the head: <script type="text/javascript" src="templates/tk_gen_free_ii/js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
      $("#block-menu").sticky({ topSpacing: 0});
    });
  </script>

Comment: Dude your code is pretty much a mess, the plugin is not working because you have more then one library on your page... use `jQuery` instead of `$` this will make the plugin work, but your page is a bunch of position absolute you should take a look on your markup again.

Comment: Looks like the URL is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Line `if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300  {` is missing a close bracket for a start.

Comment: Thanks, I added the close bracket after "300" but still nothing

Comment: When you say nothing what exactly do you mean? Are there any JS errors on the page?

Comment: no errors, just the div remain position relative, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I've made a working version based on your code example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DaveHogan/76kdr/2

In short, I'm guessing you needed a 
`$(document).ready(function(){` and missing a close bracket

`if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300 {`

should be

`if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300) {`

Comment: tried, nothing, I've put this code between the tags script language text/javascript, in the head of the page... what's wrong?

Comment: The jsfiddle above works. It's something else on your page. I assume you can see it working in jsFiddle? Is there any error in your browser console / error log?